# Constructor in class cannot be applied to give types

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, constructor, extends

I am attempting to create multiple classes that inherit from the same superclass. My first class worked perfectly. When I attempted a second one I got an error message I haven't seen before. I'm new at this so I'm not sure how to solve the issue.

This is the class

```
class Employee extends Person{
      double salary;
      private java.util.Date dateCreated;


      public Employee(){
      }

      public Employee(String name, String address, String phone_number, double salary){
         super(name, address, phone_number);
         this.salary = salary;
      }

      public String getDate(){
         java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
         return date.toString();
      }

      public double getSalary(){
         return this.salary;
      }

      public String toString(){
         return("Employee object:\n" + super.toString() + "\n" + "Salary:\t$" + getSalary() + "\n" + "Date Hired: " + getDate());
      }
   }
```

I am attempting to call the method this way

```
Employee employee = new Employee (name, address, number, salary);
System.out.println(employee.toString());
```

I am getting this error message:

```
testPerson.java:21: error: constructor Employee in class Employee cannot be applied to given types;
Employee employee = new Employee (name, address, number, salary);
                    ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String,String,String,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Here is TestPerson class

```
public class TestPerson{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        String name = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter your address: ");
        String address = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter your phone number: ");
        String number = input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter your yearly salary: ");
        double salary = input.nextDouble();
        Employee employee = new Employee (name, address, number, salary);
        System.out.println(employee.toString());
    }
}
```

This is the parent class to clear it up. I could be doing something wrong that I'm not catching.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Person{
   private String name;
   private String address;
   private String phone_number;

   public Person(){
   }

   public Person(String name, String address, String phone_number){
      this.name = name;
      this.address = address;
      this.phone_number = phone_number;
   }

   public String getName(){
      return this.name;
   }

   public String getAddress(){
      return this.address;
   }

   public String getPhone(){
      return this.phone_number;
   }

   public String toString(){
      return ("Person object:\n" + "Name:\t\t" + getName() + "\n" + "Address:\t" + getAddress() + "\n" + "Phone#:\t" + getPhone());
   }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have a `void` in front of the second Employee constructor, the one that takes 4 parameters?

Comment: i hope the Person class have three argument constructor. right ?

Comment: I don't have a void in front the constructor. Should there be one?

Comment: @ScottRobinson No you shouldn't. That would cause it to be a method and not a constructor

Comment: Also yes, the Person class has three argument constructor, it has name, address and number. Those are what I am attempting to inherit. @sarathkumar

Comment: No, there shouldn't be a `void` there, but it is a common cause for this type of error. Please show your `testPerson` class (which should be re-named `TestPerson`)

Comment: Yikes. No. All code must be posted as an edit to your original question. Else we cannot read it.

Comment: (1) Please edit the question to show the code as properly formatted text. (2) Are you sure there is exactly _one_ class `Employee` around?

Comment: Recompile, rebuild, clean your project within the IDE. Try again.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yes, there is only one class named Employee. I also currently have a Person class and a Student class, both work fine when I use them. The Student class looks very similar to the Employee class. I used it as a reference for the Employee class.

Comment: Looks good. Make sure your test doesn’t run against an “old” version of the Employee class, where you didn’t have the four-argument-constructor

Answer (score 0):

I'm following the state of this issue since the beginning now and I found it really interesting so I copied your code and test it locally and surprise like I was expecting ... no single error found.
It seems that your compiler is trying to use the constructor with no arguments instead of the second one you gived. You should verify your code if this is really this Employee class who is used in testPerson.java.

Comment: Best not to post "your code worked for me" as an answer.

Comment: this is not a "your code worked for me" answer. I'm advising him to check again his imports and the structure of his project because no one found a single mistake on his code.